# Calloc allocation is inconsistent

Tags: c, memory, calloc

I'm creating a 2d array of integers using pointers and the calloc function. The thing is that I allocate a 3x5 matrix. And indeed, there are 3 rows but 6 columns. I can't understand this behavior. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
int main() {


int **new_lib = (int **) calloc(3, sizeof(int *));

if (new_lib == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: out of memory (create_library() part 1)\n");
    exit(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    new_lib[i] = (int *) calloc(5, sizeof(int));

    if (new_lib[i] == NULL) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Error: out of memory (create_library() part 2)\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
        new_lib[i][j] = j * (i + 1) + i * (j + 1);
    }

}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
        printf("[%i][%i] = %i ", i, j, new_lib[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

And the print is correct for one more column:
`[0][0] = 0 [0][1] = 1 [0][2] = 2 [0][3] = 3 [0][4] = 4 [0][5] = 5 
[1][0] = 1 [1][1] = 4 [1][2] = 7 [1][3] = 10 [1][4] = 13 [1][5] = 16 
[2][0] = 2 [2][1] = 7 [2][2] = 12 [2][3] = 17 [2][4] = 22 [2][5] = 27`

Comment: `j < 6` --> `j < 5` else out of bound access causes U.B

Comment: Yeah that's the purpose of my question hehe.

Comment: There are only 5 columns, not 6. You're just accessing memory that's not part of the array. Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @melpomene: How do you envision it is helpful to say “Undefined behavior is undefined” to people who do not know what behavior is defined and what is not? The sentence contains no information. Even writing “You're just accessing memory that's not part of the array” does not say that doing so is undefined behavior. If people knew this behavior was undefined, they would not be asking these questions. To convey information, you need to actually state (preferably clearly, simply, and directly) what behavior is undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Achal already said that: "*out of bound access causes UB*"

Comment: @melpomene: But that is not a simple, direct, or clear statement. There are multiple steps in between. `j < 6` is the wrong condition for the loop, because it permits an iteration in which `j` is 5, and `calloc(5…)` only allocates space for an array with five elements, and the indices of those five elements are 0 to 4, and the code in the loop contains `new_lib[i][j]`, so the array is accessed with 5 as an index, and, when code accesses an array with an index out of bounds, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. In any case, saying “Undefined behavior is undefined” is not helpful.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OP already knew most of that: "*I allocate a 3x5 matrix*" and they were aware that the loop accesses 6 columns: "*there are 3 rows but 6 columns*".

Comment: @melpomene: Stating “Undefined behavior is undefined” conveys no information and is snide.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I disagree.

Comment: To conclude, I said that is inconsistent because if I try the same but for a row there is a SEGfault. I was surprised that it was not the case for the columns. So, I wonder if I did something wrong or if there is like a security in calloc and allocates one more. It seems that the answer is no. Just "lucky" that it works for one more column, but I shouldn't use it because is U.B. Right?

Comment: However, I don’t understand why the compilator let me access freely to parts of the memory like that… Not even a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always consistent. Here you have some more generic. There is no allocation error checks for better code readability.

```
void *allocate(size_t selem, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    void **array = calloc(rows, sizeof(void *));
    
    for(size_t row =0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        array[row] = calloc(cols, selem);
    }
    return array;
}


int main()
{
    int **array = allocate(sizeof(int), 3, 5);
    
    for(size_t r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        printf("%p\n",array[r]);   
    }

    for(size_t r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(size_t c = 0; c < 5; c++)
        {
            array[r][c] = r*10 + c;   
        }
    }
    for(size_t r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(size_t c = 0; c < 5; c++)
        {
            printf("%02d ", array[r][c]);   
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/Hko5Wjy5V

## edit

You can use other types. Just pass the correct size and assign the correct pointer type

```
typedef struct
{
    double  x[1000];
    int y[500]
    /* more stuff */
}MYSTRUCT;

int main()
{
    MYSTRUCT *ptr = allocate(sizeof(MYSTRUCT), 10, 50);
```

Comment: Thanks for your code! Is simple and readable. Sadly I simplified my question to an array of integers but un fact is a more complex intrication of structs and stuff like that. But I'll take inspiration of what you did.

Comment: it does not matter just change the size of the element (selement) and the type of the pointer